# Linear Dependence Using Gaussian Elimination

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 4\\ 1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$$ 
>   Find if there are linear independent or not, if so show a vector that is linear dependent

I know that the row rank is equal to the column rank so I can look on the matrix of the vectors as is meaning

\begin{pmatrix} 1& 4 &1\\ 2 &1&1 \end{pmatrix} or 
\begin{pmatrix} 1& 2 \\ 4 &1 \\ 1&1 \end{pmatrix}

In the first case I am looking at $$\alpha \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 4\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+ \beta \begin{pmatrix} 2\\ 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

So the only solution is $\alpha=\beta=0$ so I know it is linear dependent, but I do not know how to generate one vector from the two others.

Unlike

$$\alpha \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2 \end{pmatrix}+ \beta \begin{pmatrix} 4\\ 1\end{pmatrix}+\gamma \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

In one case I am looking at the $\ker(T)$ and the other $\text{Im}(T)$?

Comment: A vector linearly dependent on the vector you have are simply any combination you can imagine. The simplest would be if $\alpha, \beta, \gamma = 1$.

Comment: (1) You may fix $T$ at your will to facilitate the discussion, like $T = [\mathsf{L}_A]$, where $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&4&1\\2&1&1\end{pmatrix}
$.(2) If you know `\tag{ging}` equation, then it's easier for as to follow: $$\alpha \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}+\beta \begin{pmatrix}4\\ 1\end{pmatrix}+\gamma\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\tag{T1}\label{T1}$$In $\eqref{T1}$, you are finding $$\lbrace(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)\mid A (\alpha,\beta,\gamma)^T=0 \rbrace$$ so you're finding $\mathrm{ker}(T)$. For the other equation, you're finding $\rm{ker}(\sf{L}_{A^T})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\4&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
you're looking at two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$; doing row reduction will only show that the original vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are linearly dependent.

With row reduction on the other matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 1 \\
0 & -7 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
you get that the third vector is in the span of the first two. If you also find the reduced row echelon form
$$
\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1/7
\end{pmatrix}
\to
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 3/7 \\
0 & 1 & 1/7
\end{pmatrix}
$$
you also prove that
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
=
\frac{3}{7}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}
+
\frac{1}{7}\begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
because row operations don't change linear relations between the columns.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is to find $\alpha,\beta$ such that:
$$\alpha \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2 \end{pmatrix}+ \beta \begin{pmatrix} 4\\ 1\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$
Which can simply be written:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4\\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \alpha\\ \beta \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$
You can now use row reduction to get your answer.